# Session_start doesn't work in login page

Tags: php, ajax, session

I'm currently working on a login-page. There are several files:

`login.php` - here you can enter your password and username. An AJAX-request will be sent.

`checkLogin.php` - the username and password will be checked with the database. If these are correct, the page must redirect to `home.php`

`home.php` - this is the home-page.

**Note:** I know that there is a lot of injection in my code, but that's not important at this moment.

**EDIT**:

The SESSION-value is set. However, the redirect to`home.php` doesn't work when `$result->num_rows > 0`

**The problem is**: the page doesn't redirect after giving my username and password. And that SESSION-values aren't set if I try to access `home.php` because the page keeps redirecting to `login.php`

login.php

```
<?php 
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
Login
    <input type="text" id="user" name="user" placeholder="username">
    <input type="text" id="pass" name="pass" placeholder="password">
    <input type="button" name="submit" value="VERSTUUR" id="button">
    <div id="answer"></div>
</form>
</body>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#button').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var user = $('#user').val();
            var pass = $('#pass').val();
            $.ajax({
                url:'checkLogin.php',
                type:'POST',
                data: {
                    user:user,
                    pass:pass,
                },
                success: function(data){
                    $("#answer").html(data);
                },
                error: function(data){
                    alert(data);
                }
            })
        })
    })
</script>
</html>
```

checkLogin.php:

```
<?php
$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "root", "user1");
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE user='" . $_POST['user'] . "' AND pass='" . $_POST['pass'] . "'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0){
    $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['user'];
    header('Location: http://localhost:8888/Blog/home.php');
    exit();
} 

$conn->close();

?>
```

home.php

```
<?php 
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){ //if login in session is not set
    header('Location: http://localhost:8888/Blog/login.php');
    exit;
} else {
    echo "Welcome!";
}
 ?>
```

Comment: please remember you need to start session on each page. Better will be keep session_start() in a file or head and include this on all page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the `<?php session_start();?>` at the beginning of `checkLogin.php`

Answer (score 0):

Add `session_start();` to `checkLogin.php`:

```
<?php
session_start(); //<- here
$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "root", "user1");
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE user='" . $_POST['user'] . "' AND pass='" . $_POST['pass'] . "'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0){
    $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['user'];
    header('Location: http://localhost:8888/Blog/home.php');
    exit();
} 

$conn->close();

?>
```

Comment: The SESSION-value is fixed! However, the page doesn't redirect to home.php when $result->num_rows > 0

Answer (score -1):

copy `<?php session_start();?>`  paste on  checkLogin.php

and read this for any other query 
https://www.formget.com/login-form-in-php/

Comment: I don't know why would you link this tutorial, it is one of the worst ones ever. I do not understand how is it possible that it was written last year, it wouldn't even run on the PHP version available in 2018.